# An observation from IMO 2010 P6 using sets of vectors

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

Here is a observation which I got while working on 2010 IMO P6 but couldn't prove on my own.

For any positive integer $n$, consider the sequence of sets of $n$-element vectors starting with
$$\begin{aligned} b_1&=\{[1,0,0,\ldots,0,0]\}, \\ b_2&=\{[0,1,0,\ldots,0,0]\}, \\ &\vdots \\ b_n&=\{[0,0,0,\ldots,0,1]\}\end{aligned}$$
and such that for $i>n$,
$$b_i = \bigcup_{j=1}^{i-1} (b_j+b_{i-j}),$$
where the sum of sets of sets is taken pairwise and elementwise. For example,
$$\begin{aligned}\{[0,1],\,[0,2]\}+\{[0,3],\,[0,5]\}&=\{[0,1]+[0,3],\,[0,1]+[0,5],\,[0,2]+[0,3],\,[0,2]+[0,5]\}\\ &=\{[0,4],\,[0,6],\,[0,5],\,[0,7]\}.\end{aligned}$$

For any $e \in b_i$, the dot product of $e$ with $[1, 2, \ldots, n]$ is $i$. This is quite obvious to prove using induction and the distributivity of the dot product.

What I am trying to show is this: Given any $n$, for sufficiently large $i$, the set $b_i$ consists of all vectors $e$ with integral coefficients, whose dot product with $[1, 2, \ldots, n]$ is $i$, such that for $1 \le k \le n$, the $k$-th entry of $e$ is between the smallest and greatest $k$-th entry among all vectors in $b_i$.

---

A nice polynomial trick:-

There is a nice relation between the problem with polynomials that is rather than working with vectors we deal with polynomials

for example we can also write $[1,0,..,0]$ as $x$

and $[0,0,0...,1]$ as $x^{n}$ basically elements in vector represent the coefficients,all properities of vectors needed are still preserved [basically elementwise addition here though lol] .

So now

we have $b_1={x},b_2={x^{2}},...,b_n={x^{n}}$

we can still differentiate everything maintaing the reccurence relation.

We now give an alternate proof to our dot product claim which makes it seem much more natural using this

so say we now we deal with

The dot product of that vector[if that vector corresponds to the polynomial P(x)] with the other vector basically is the value of $P'(1)$

$b_1=\{1\},b_2=\{2x\},...,b_n=\{nx^{n-1}\}$ Now just plug in $x=1$ everywhere
As reccurence is still maintained just induction finishes the rest .

$c_1=\{1\},c_2=\{2\},...,c_n=\{n\}$

Also i feel like computing the cardinalities of $b_i$ somehow would help as once we prove our claim we eventually should a have nice formula for $|b_i|$

I intutively also feel that

for each $n$ there exist

$n$ integers

Such that if i do similar definition of the seuquence starting with those $n$ integers the cardinialities of $b_i$ in both of the sequence will eventually be the same .

Here is how i thought of that :-

if $n=2$

i have $b_1=\{[1,0]\},b_2=\{[0,1]\}$  now u have the obvious solution $[1],[0]$ too but here is another way i thought of it

I again resort to polynomials

Consider rather the polynomials

$b_1=\{[x^3]\},b_2=\{[x^2]\}$

again we define new sequence
by differentiating everything and plugging in $x=1$

$c_1=\{[3]\},c_2=\{[2]\}$

Observe like the last dot product here the set $c_i$ determines all possible dot products with $[3,2]$ as a vector $[x,y]$ is uniquely determined by $[x+2y,3x+2y]$ in a set $b_i$ .

as $x+2y$ is fixed along a set $b_i$ basically we just need the no of distinct $3x+2y$ for its cardinality or the cardinality of $c_i$ we can use this process to go from $n$ dimensional vectors to $n-1$ other than obvious solutions. i feel we should somehow be able to reduce to $1$ also .

Any help on trying to prove the claim will be appreciated hope i didnt miss anything simple.

Thanks for reading

Also in the last section to write it properly i think that

for any $n$

there exist $x_1,x_2,...,x_n \in \mathbb{Z}$

such that if i define the sequence $c_i$ starting with

$c_1=\{[x_1]\},c_2=\{[x_2]\},...,c_n=\{[x_n]\}$

following same reccurence relation.

then $|c_i|=|b_i|$ for a sufficinetly large $i$

Note finding such rationals is enough , and finding irrationals of such kind are easy

let $p_1,p_2,...,p_n$ denote the first $n$ primes

Consider the map from any vector $v=[e_1,e_2,...,e_n] \to e_1\sqrt{p_1}+e_2\sqrt{p_2}+....+e_n\sqrt{p_n}$
Proving it works requires some NT[though ig is also theorom ]
and perform these on the two first $n$ to get the needed $x_i$ now ofcourse we can get a arbitarily close rational approximation of these such that $|c_i|=|b_i|$ for a small enough $i$

Comment: Your recurrence has the same name as the initial sequence of vectors. Is the idea that you're defining a sequence $b_{i,n}$ where $b_{i,0}$ are the singletons of elementary basis vectors, and $b_{i,n+1}$ are defined in terms of $b_{i,n}$ through your recurrence?

Comment: Also, this would be somewhat easier to read if you didn't spread it across so many lines. Try writing this as a few neat paragraphs.

Comment: @ViHdzP not a sequence of vectors of a sequence of sets of some vectors each vector having n elements like a set $\{v_1,v_2,...v_k\}$ where $v_i$ is individually a vector of n elements

Comment: Ya i know its long and stuff but like i tried by best to separate things there are actually bunch of stuff in it

Comment: Still, that doesn't answer my question. When you write $b_i = \bigcup_{j=1}^{i-1}b_j+b_{i-j}$, is this supposed to be a step-by-step procedure applied to the original list of sets?

Comment: Its a reccurence relation for example 

$b_1=\{[1,0]\},b_2=\{[0,1]\}$ and then $b_3$ is $\{[1,0]+[0,1]\}=\{[1,1]\}$ and $b_4$ is union of $b_3+b_1$ and $b_2+b_2$ or $\{[0,2]\}$ and $\{[2,1]\}$ so $b_4=\{[0,2],[2,1]\}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152137/discussion-between-lucid-and-vihdzp).

Comment: An initial result that might be worth showing is that for any $k$, for sufficiently large $i$, the set of $k$-th entries in $b_i$ is an interval.

Answer (score 0):

[I am the author of the problem as well].

So after lot of work i established a  weaker version of the claim, hopefully someone can work further on it and the answer is suprisingly short and simple.

Call a n dimensional vector $v$ "non-pairing" if

Case 1:  n even
there exist $i$ such that if a= $i$th entry of $v$ and $b$=$n+1-i$th entry of $v$ then$0$ not $ \in \{a,b\}$

Case 2: n odd
there exist $i $ such that if a= $i$th entry of $v$ and $b$=$n+1-i$th entry of $v$ then$0$ not $ \in \{a,b\}$
and the $\frac{n+1}{2}$th entry isnt $0$ or $1$ .

Here is what i managed to prove, for all $i$ , all vectors with integral coefficients and are  "non-pairing" such that its dot product with $[1,2,...,n]$ is $i$ are in $b_i$ .
Firstly i define the infinite set,

$S=\bigcup_{j=n+1}^{\infty} b_j$

Then i establish a claim

Claim 1:- if $e \in S$ then $e+$ 1st element of $b_i \in S, \forall 1 \leq i \leq n$

This is not so hard  to observe say $e \in b_j$

now $b_{j+1}$ should contain the vetor $e+$ first element of $b_{1}$,
$b_{j+2}$ should contain $e$+ first element of $b_{2}$
and so on ending till $b_{j+n}$ containing $e$+first element of $b_{n}$

Case 1: $n$ even

Now it is easy to observe
$[1,0,...,1] \in b_{n+1}$

$[0,1,....,1,0] \in b_{n+1}$
...

$[0,....,1,1,0,....,0] \in b_{n+1}$

hence they are also an element of $S$ .
By claim 1

all vectors with non negative integral coefficients such that

its first term $>0$ and last term $>0$ should also be in $S$.
or if second term $>0$ and last term $>0$ .

and so on

hence all vectors with non negative integral coefficients that are "non-pairing" are in $S$ .

After this use dot product claim to decide which $b_i$ those elements are in  , this finishes the proof

Case 2: $n$ odd

then

$[1,0,0,...,1] \in b_{n+1}$

$[0,1,...,1] \in b_{n+1}$
....

$[0,0,...,2,0,0...,0] \in b_{n+1}$

Rest of the proof stays similar

and for $b_1,b_2,...,b_n$ its easy to verify manually